# Use CSS tag inside PHP code

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I'm trying to show/hide two lines of text depending on whether a `WooCommerce` category is empty or has any products in it. Those lines are inserted in text blocks using `Elementor` and I've assigned a `CSS #ID` to each one, so I can control it.

Now, in a custom functions plugin I have, I want to add a function to control what phrase to hide using a `css` rule of the type: `display:none;`. The code I have now is:

```php
function show_outlet_msg($content){
    $term = get_term( 40, 'product_cat' );
    $total_products=$term->count;
    if ($total_products>0){
        //Have a products 
    } else {
        //No products
    }
}

add_filter('astra_entry_content_before','show_outlet_msg');
```

Now I would like to apply that if there are products in Outlet, the text that there are no products in Outlet should be hidden:

```css
#txt_outlet_zero{
display: none;
}
```

And in case there are no products, hide the one that says there are:

```css
#txt_outlet_head{
display: none;
}
```

How can I apply these CSS rules from the php code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can add styles in filters.
I tested the below code in wp_head action and worked perfectly:

```
function show_outlet_msg(){
    $term = get_term( 40, 'product_cat' );
    $total_products=$term->count;
    if ($total_products>0){
        $html = '<style> #txt_outlet_zero{ display: none; } </style>';
    } else {
        $html = '<style> #txt_outlet_head{ display: none; } </style>';
    }
    echo $html;
}

add_action('wp_head','show_outlet_msg');
```

Comment: You can hook to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/).

Answer (score 0):

You can hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse383179_inline_style' );
function wpse383179_inline_style() {
    $term = get_term( 40, 'product_cat' );
    $total_products=$term->count;
    if ($total_products>0){
        $css = '#txt_outlet_zero { display: none; }';
    } else {
        $css = '#txt_outlet_head { display: none; }';
    }
    wp_add_inline_style( '{your-css-id}', $css );
}
```

The tricky part is determining what `your-css-id` should be. You can view the source of a given page and check the `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` tags. The CSS ID for each of them (assuming they've been properly registered and enqueued for WordPress) will be in the `id` attribute, with `-css` appended to it. So, if you see, eg,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="my-styles-css" src="/path/to/stylesheet.css" />
```

... then the `{your-css-id}` bit in my code snippet should be `my-styles`.

### However

That said, is there a reason to generate two different CSS IDs for this? There's never going to be a situation where the `$total_products` is 0 and greater than 0. There may be an easier way, eg, adding a single `<div>` and changing the content inside it based on the product count.